# Codename One code to create UI in a declarative way

Tags: codenameone

A while ago, I read a Codename One blog post about creating UI in a declarative way (using something similar to a json syntax), but I'm not finding anymore the link.

Could you give me the link, please? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Found:

**Introduction to UIFragment**

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/introduction-to-uifragment.html

Comment: The link was not easy to find because this issue on the seach: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3034